# Wordpress and Conditional IE statments

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I know this question has been asked 100x but I can't seem to find a solution in the other articles. I have gone through many support questions on here and other sites without resolve.  I'm trying to add conditional IE statements to my WordPress theme for version 8 and under and then for 9.  Here's what my head section looks like (not sure why it's not all showing one block of code on here.. sorry about that):

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie9.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]-->
```

I have tried just one statment using  with no luck.
I also tried a direct link the css using the full URL.

When the page loads I see the way it should look using the ie.css (mainly I changed the background so it was obvious) and then it quickly changes to my default stylesheet.  When I inspect using Firebug it shows it using the default stylesheet.
Any ideas?
thanks.

********UPDATE*************
I guess I needed to step away for the weekend.  I realized today that the page I had been looking at was my home.php page I had set in WP.  That was the only page on my site that wasn't using the header.php file and had it's only link to the stylesheets.  Thus once I added the conditional statements to that page, it sees the IE style sheets now.  I feel like a bonehead, but sometimes taking a step back can be the best answer.  Thanks for the other replies though!

Comment: if gte IE 9 = greater than ie9, so IE9 is not included.

Comment: No, `gte` = `greater than or equal to`.

Comment: thanks. I read that gte IE 9 included 9 and anything above.  I changed it, but it's still only seeing my default stylesheeet in IE 8 and 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized today that the page I had been looking at was my home.php page I had set in WP. That was the only page on my site that wasn't using the header.php file and had it's only link to the stylesheets. Thus once I added the conditional statements to that page, it sees the IE style sheets now. I feel like a bonehead, but sometimes taking a step back can be the best answer. Thanks for the other replies thou

Answer (score 0):

IE css will only load in IE browsers So it will not be view-able in Mozilla using firebug.
In Mozilla, page will only use the default one.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  I am testing in IE.  I'm using Firebug Lite in IE to inspect the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two conditional-hide comments (ie. they are invisible to non-IE browsers). You need to then add a conditional-reveal comment with `if !IE` for all other browsers. See [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for more information.

EDIT: Also, Firebug may not recognise conditional comments even if you're running it in IE. You should use the F12 Developer Tools.

Comment: thanks. I've added that in to be safe.  However I still have no luck.  Even in developer tools when looking at the HTML it shows it as: 
    <link href="http://johnmobley.com.veddio.net/wp-content/themes/Mobley/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that conditional comments can be kinda finicky for some reason.

First, make sure they are loaded After your base style sheet, as it may be they are loaded but overwriten by your base style sheet.

Also, I've had conditional stylesheets not load, and then moved the code somewhere else and had it work.  Make sure your document validates and there isn't anything else around that might disturb parsing of those statements.

What else is going on in your header?  Just to help us troubleshoot?

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I would post my entire header but the post keeps chopping up my code into segments.  How can I post all the code in one code block?